# Infragistics Ultragrid valueList/UltraDropDown

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

What event to I need to handle to allow users to add "fruit" the either a valuelist or ultra dropdown.

Since it is a KVP I always get format exception

```
Dictionary<int,string> fruits = new Dictionary<int,string>();



 private void FruitInit()
     {
    //Create some fruit        
    fruits.Add(-1,"apple");
            fruits.Add(-2,"banana");

            //Create and add to the ultraDropDown
            UltraDropDown fruitUltraDropDown = new UltraDropDown();
            fruitUltraDropDown.DataSource = fruits.ToList();
            fruitUltraDropDown.DisplayMember = "Value";
            fruitUltraDropDown.ValueMember = "Key";
            MyUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["MyColumn"].ValueList = fruitUltraDropDown;
        }
```

What event can I handle so when a user types "grape" I can add it to the dictionary with my own key, and it gets added to the dropdownlist. Currently if I type "grape in the cell, I just get a format exception.

Regards

_Eric

Comment: Very confusing question; `UltraWinGrid` and `UltraDropDown` are unrelated controls. What "cell" are you talking about? Adding anything to the `Dictionary` will be impossible because you throw it away after generating the `ValueList`. Also, post the error you are getting.

Comment: @Dour Thanks, I am unsure what is confusing. I have added a ultraDropDown to "MyColumn" in my ultragrid. This is working fine, users can select "apple" || "banana". Users need to be able to type there own value i.e. "grape", but when they do so I get a format exception saying it cannot convert it to int.32, which is expected as it's valueMember is an int. I am looking for an event to handle so I could add it back to the dictionary and rebind the list. Typically with binding sources I would handle the AddNew and would add my own index along with the user defined text(-3,"grape") in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a response from Mike@infragistics, I didn't know about ValueListResolved

[Answer from Mike](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/50433/265154.aspx#265154)

> There are a number of events you could
>   use. I would probably use
>   BeforeCellUpdate or maybe
>   BeforeExitEditMode.
>
> Either way, what you would do is use
>   the ValueListResolved property on the
>   cell to get the ValueList and then you
>   can use the GetValue method to try to
>   find a matching item on the list. Use
>   the cell.EditorResolved.Text to get
>   the current edit text in the cell for
>   your search.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an "UltraDropDown" for the value list, you can handle it's "BeforeDropDown" event.  Compare the "used" values in the grid to the values in the UltraDropDown, then hide the ones that are in use.
Worked for me.

```
    private void BindApprovalsTab()
    {
        uddApproverList.BeforeDropDown -= new CancelEventHandler(uddApproverList_BeforeDropDown);
        uddApproverList.DataSource = dsFindingDetails.Tables["Approvers"];
        uddApproverList.DisplayMember = "fldDisplayName";
        uddApproverList.ValueMember = "fldRoleGID";
        uddApproverList.Width = 150;
        uddApproverList.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["fldRoleGID"].Hidden = true;
        uddApproverList.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["fldDisplayName"].Header.Caption = "Role";
        uddApproverList.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["fldDisplayName"].Width = uddApproverList.Width;
        uddApproverList.BeforeDropDown += new CancelEventHandler(uddApproverList_BeforeDropDown);

        ugActionItemApprovals.DataSource = dsFindingDetails.Tables["tblIssueApprovals"];

    }

    void uddApproverList_BeforeDropDown(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //assume all rows show
        foreach (UltraGridRow udr in uddApproverList.Rows)
        {
            udr.Hidden = false;
        }
        //can we remove already used entries?
        foreach (UltraGridRow udr in uddApproverList.Rows)
        {
            string sDDRoleGID = udr.Cells["fldRoleGID"].Value.ToString();
            foreach (UltraGridRow ur in ugActionItemApprovals.Rows)
            {
                if (ur.Cells["fldApprovalRequiredBy"].Value.ToString() == sDDRoleGID)
                {
                    udr.Hidden = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be relevant to your question, but there are many strange things in your code.

```
UltraDropDown fruitUltraDropDown = new UltraDropDown();
```

Infragistics includes wizards to create, populate, and display controls in the designer.cs file. Instantiating a control like this throws away all the designer data and creates a new, default control. Do you really intend this? Is this an excerpt from the designer.cs file?

```
fruitUltraDropDown.DataSource = fruits.ToList();
```

This creates a new `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` from your `Dictionary`. `fruits` is now unreachable and eligible for garbage collection, any change made to it will never be propagated to `fruitUltraDropDown`. Why are you creating `fruits` only to throw it away?

> What event can I handle so when a user types "grape"...

Types where? `fruitUltraDropDown`? The designer data has been thrown away so `fruitUltraDropDown` is not editable, unless there is a lot of code you are not showing. `MyUltraGrid`? You do not show any code for this, so no one can have any idea what it implements. A text field? Programmatic data? A total mystery.

> I can add it to the dictionary...

Adding anything to `Dictionary` is pointless because you no longer use it. If you want to add it to `ultraDropDown1.DataSource` you have to add a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`:

```
var ds = ultraDropDown1.DataSource as List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>;
ds.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(-3, "grape"));
```

This will just add the entry to the backing store. If you want to include it in `ultraDropDown1`:

```
ultraDropDown1.DataBind();
```

If this is not helpful you must add enough information to your question so that someone without your source code can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: that is all the source, I have edited the code to show the FruitInit, hopefully that makes it clearer. The  AfterCellUpdate was the event I needed, to check if the user entry was in the list, if not add it to the dictionary and update  the dropDown for other rows to use.